# Tricky matrix basis question

Tags: matrices

I have two possible answers that I came up with for the basis of the column space for the matrix $\begin{bmatrix}2& 4\\ 4 &8\\ 1 & 2\\ 0 &0\end{bmatrix}$ ..

Is it a matrix with the bottom row removed and e1 and e2 added $\begin{bmatrix}2& 0 & 0\\ 4 &1 & 0\\ 1 & 0 & 1\end{bmatrix}$

or does the bottom row stay $\begin{bmatrix}2& 0 & 0 & 0\\ 4 &1 & 0 &0\\ 1 & 0 & 1 & 0\\ 0 & 0 & 0& 1\end{bmatrix}$ ?

Comment: Question is unclear. Can you explain in details.

Comment: Basis of a matrix is meaning less. What is the vector space here ?

Comment: It looks to be R^4 so I guess the last answer is correct.

Comment: It does not make sense to ask for the basis for the matrix. Perhaps, you seek a basis for the column space? or, a basis for the row space?

Comment: @user2514676, you should make a further effort to render a sound question. As for now your question makes no sense at all and it is even hard to understand what you could have meant to ask. Common, this is college/university level, we **must** strive to be clearer!

Comment: I'm looking for the basis of the column space

Comment: A basis of a vector space is a set of vectors, not a matrix; while your question now makes sense, neither of your prospective answers is correct (even if you interpret a matrix as determining its set of columns). What's your understanding of a "column space", and of a "basis"?

Comment: Getting into lengthy discussions about all the applicable theorems doesn't seem to be the quickest path to answering the original question. My two answers follow the same pattern as other answers for similar problems already given to me. If neither of the two answers I provided are correct, I need to know what the correct answer is.